# My application relies Google play services, which is not supported by your device. contact the manufacturer for assistance

Tags: android

I am creating a Google Map application on 4.4.2 (API 19) and added all Google Play services, Google repository and all packages under 4.4.2 (API 19).
But I'm getting this error:

> My application relies Google play services, which is not supported by
>   your device. contact the manufacturer for assistance.

Comment: I received this error after my Nexus 10 crashed during an update. Obviously nexus is part of the Google play ecosystem; there are multiple causes for this error, unfortunately.

Answer (score 13):

**Possible solution:**

1. Make sure you are using the latest version of Google Play Service & most importantly your Play Services isn't disabled. You can download the latest version here,

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms

Uninstall any previous updated before installing the new one

Goto -> Settings -> Apps -> Google Play Services -> Uninstall installed updates

2. Make sure your current date/time is correct.

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

If you are using an emulator you should keep in mind that emulator doesn't support **Google Play Services** by default. What you can do is download and install **Google APIs** from **SDK Manager** then create a new device in emulator using the **Google APIs** as target.

First install Google APIs from SDK Manager,

[image]

Create a virtual device like this,

For Android Studio,

[image]

For Eclipse,

[image]

Comment: Its running on android emulator.

Comment: For me this solution worked in Android Studio. At this moment the IDE looks a bit different but the solution still relies in these two steps provided by Prokash:

1. Install Google APIs from SDK Manager.

You can find it in Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Tools tab

Here I installed the 4 Google Play * options

2. In Tools > Device Manager create a Nexus device simulator

Answer (score 0):

Very Late, just adding if it could help someone else.
In the latest versions of AVD emulators if you set a PIN Code/Pattern Security and checked "Require to start device". It happens just disable it or first make your Emulator boot completely before you run application. This happened To Me
[image: This Appeared To Me When I Run Directly]

After This I Press Back Button and entered pin and made device boot. After boot when I re-run, It Worked Fine. by the way I was using Captcha Service which required play services.
[image]