# My app won't run without Google Play services with android studio?

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

i'm tring to create google map sample app ,but i have a problem during Run the application on Simulator, This message appears : my app won't run without google play services which are not supported by your device
,  Look at these a picture :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHPrO.png)

```
//log cat errror 


 05-28 08:14:19.593 660-674/system_process E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.android.systemui
                                                             PID: 748
                                                             Reason: executing service com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService
                                                             Load: 5.34 / 1.87 / 0.67
                                                             CPU usage from 0ms to 13211ms later:
                                                               87% 660/system_server: 12% user + 75% kernel / faults: 5065 minor 14 major
                                                               51% 370/surfaceflinger: 2.6% user + 48% kernel / faults: 18 minor 1 major
                                                               37% 748/com.android.systemui: 4.7% user + 32% kernel / faults: 5005 minor 16 major
                                                               24% 8/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 24% kernel
                                                               15% 102/debuggerd: 1.3% user + 14% kernel / faults: 2346 minor
                                                               20% 290/local_opengl: 0.3% user + 20% kernel / faults: 8 minor
                                                               11% 54/kworker/0:1: 0% user + 11% kernel
                                                               12% 20/ksoftirqd/3: 0% user + 12% kernel
                                                               12% 114/adbd: 0.3% user + 12% kernel / faults: 80 minor
                                                               9.8% 326/mediaserver: 1.5% user + 8.3% kernel / faults: 105 minor 3 major
                                                               5.7% 16/ksoftirqd/2: 0% user + 5.7% kernel
                                                               5.7% 394/bootanimation: 0.4% user + 5.2% kernel
                                                               3.9% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 3.9% kernel
                                                               3.1% 284/healthd: 0.1% user + 2.9% kernel
                                                               2.9% 938/zygote: 0.5% user + 2.4% kernel / faults: 335 minor
                                                               1% 59/kworker/3:1: 0% user + 1% kernel
                                                               0.3% 15/migration/2: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
                                                               0.2% 11/migration/1: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                               0.1% 7/migration/0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                               0.8% 19/migration/3: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
                                                               0.5% 12/ksoftirqd/1: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
                                                               0.3% 1//init: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
                                                               0.3% 79/logd: 0% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 3 minor
                                                               0.3% 177/logcat: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
                                                               0.3% 286/servicemanager: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
                                                               0.1% 58/kworker/2:1H: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                               0.2% 324/netd: 0% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 17 minor
                                                               0.1% 56/kworker/2:1: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                               0% 30/kworker/1:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                               0% 77/jbd2/sdb3-8: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                               0% 98/genyd: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                               0% 291/local_gps: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 5 minor
                                                               0% 723/wpa_supplicant: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                               0% 732/sdcard: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 20 minor
                                                              +0% 1008/kworker/1:2: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                             62% TOTAL: 4.1% user + 49% kernel + 2.3% iowait + 7.1% softirq
                                                             CPU usage from 12446ms to 13050ms later:
                                                               107% 660/system_server: 16% user + 91% kernel / faults: 272 minor
                                                                 41% 664/Signal Catcher: 6.7% user + 34% kernel
                                                                 17% 672/Binder_2: 2.6% user + 14% kernel
                                                                 12% 671/Binder_1: 2.6% user + 9.3% kernel
                                                                 12% 674/ActivityManager: 0% user + 12% kernel
                                                                 8% 984/RenderThread: 1.3% user + 6.7% kernel
                                                                 5.3% 802/Thread-74: 1.3% user + 4% kernel
                                                                 5.3% 992/Binder_5: 0% user + 5.3% kernel
                                                                 4% 673/android.bg: 1.3% user + 2.6% kernel
                                                                 2.6% 686/SensorService: 0% user + 2.6% kernel
                                                               88% 370/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 88% kernel / faults: 1 minor
                                                                 32% 370/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 32% kernel
                                                                 17% 1012/Binder_4: 0% user + 17% kernel
                                                                 12% 390/POSIX timer 1: 0% user + 12% kernel
                                                                 9.3% 377/Binder_2: 0% user + 9.3% kernel
                                                                 6.6% 376/DispSync: 0% user + 6.6% kernel
                                                                 6.6% 391/EventThread: 1.3% user + 5.3% kernel
                                                                 4% 392/EventControl: 0% user + 4% kernel
                                                                 2.6% 382/VSyncThread: 0% user + 2.6% kernel
                                                                 1.3% 624/Binder_3: 0% user + 1.3% kernel
                                                               25% 394/bootanimation: 0% user + 25% kernel
                                                                 18% 403/BootAnimation: 1.3% user + 17% kernel
                                                                 8% 400/Binder_1: 0% user + 8% kernel
                                                               18% 290/local_opengl: 0% user + 18% kernel / faults: 6 minor
                                                                 14% 379/local_opengl: 0% user + 14% kernel
                                                                +0% 1014/local_opengl: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                               19% 748/com.android.systemui: 0% user + 19% kernel / faults: 105 minor 4 major
                                                                 17% 748/ndroid.systemui: 0% user + 17% kernel
                                                               6.6% 8/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 6.6% kernel
                                                               3.3% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 3.3% kernel
                                                               1.2% 114/adbd: 0% user + 1.2% kernel / faults: 7 minor
                                                                 1.8% 114/adbd: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
                                                                 0.6% 170/adbd: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
                                                                 0.6% 171/adbd: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
                                                               0.5% 59/kworker/3:1: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
                                                               0.6% 723/wpa_supplicant: 0.6% user + 0% kernel
                                                             62% TOTAL: 7.9% user + 48% kernel + 0.7% iowait + 5.5% softirq
05-28 08:14:19.612 660-674/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 74


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hamoda.g_maps">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <!--
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAXhBdyKxUo_cb-EkSgWJQTdqR0QjLcqes" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>


    package com.example.hamoda.g_maps;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera.
     * In this case, we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device.
     * This method will only be triggered once the user has installed
     Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng TutorialsPoint = new LatLng(21, 57);
        mMap.addMarker(new
                MarkerOptions().position(TutorialsPoint).title("Tutorialspoint.com"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(TutorialsPoint));
    }
}



    <resources>
    <!--
    TODO: Before you run your application, you need a Google Maps API key.
    To get one, follow this link, follow the directions and press "Create" at the end:
    https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=54:0A:E2:07:DA:48:7C:25:5A:3D:84:1F:93:22:55:AE:35:0C:0A:AC%3Bcom.example.hamoda.g_maps
    You can also add your credentials to an existing key, using these values:
    Package name:
    54:0A:E2:07:DA:48:7C:25:5A:3D:84:1F:93:22:55:AE:35:0C:0A:AC
    SHA-1 certificate fingerprint:
    54:0A:E2:07:DA:48:7C:25:5A:3D:84:1F:93:22:55:AE:35:0C:0A:AC
    Alternatively, follow the directions here:
    https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get-key
    Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
    string in this file.
    -->
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">
        AIzaSyCryt_PB6SwbJOEuyxdjCh1WDc_j4C7ln0
    </string>
</resources>


    <resources>
    <!--
    TODO: Before you run your application, you need a Google Maps API key.
    To get one, follow this link, follow the directions and press "Create" at the end:
    https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=54:0A:E2:07:DA:48:7C:25:5A:3D:84:1F:93:22:55:AE:35:0C:0A:AC%3Bcom.example.hamoda.g_maps
    You can also add your credentials to an existing key, using these values:
    Package name:
    54:0A:E2:07:DA:48:7C:25:5A:3D:84:1F:93:22:55:AE:35:0C:0A:AC
    SHA-1 certificate fingerprint:
    54:0A:E2:07:DA:48:7C:25:5A:3D:84:1F:93:22:55:AE:35:0C:0A:AC
    Alternatively, follow the directions here:
    https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get-key
    Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
    string in this file.
    -->
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">
        AIzaSyCryt_PB6SwbJOEuyxdjCh1WDc_j4C7ln0
    </string>
</resources>
```

Comment: be sure to create the emulator with google APIs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My application relies Google play services, which is not supported by your device. contact the manufacturer for assistance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890714/my-application-relies-google-play-services-which-is-not-supported-by-your-devic)

Answer (score 0):

Use a emulator system image with Google Play store installed to ensure that you have the latest version of Google Play Services (which Google Maps example relies on).  You can create an AVD use the API 24 x86 Google Play Images or the Android O Google Play Images.
[image: Google Play Store version of system Images]